# Getting different Data Disk id's in different API of same VM in azure rest API Calls?

Tags: java, rest, azure

@azuresupport #azTechHelp
Rest API : -`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resources?api-version=2018-02-01`   giving me one of the DataDisk id as `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1`

while Rest API : - `https://management.azure.com/{id-of-that-vm-to-which-that-dataDisk is attached}?api-version=2018-10-01` giving me dataDisk id as : `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1`.

Is this expected? why different resource group id?

[image: 1st API result]

[image: 2nd API result]

Comment: I call the first api, the result should also be like `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1`.

Comment: i added the screenshots. i am not getting datadisk id as : /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1 as you mentioned

Comment: You missed the `resourceGroups` in your question and I think you are better to hide the sensitive information like subscription id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I edited the answer i.e added proper api and hided subscriptionId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, the resource group name in the resource id is case insensitive, no need to care about it.

The resource id 
`/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1` and `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/TEST/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/datadisk1` are the same.

Refer to : [Naming rules and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#naming-rules-and-restrictions)

[image]

Comment: I will just confirm with azure support and see documentation if found that resource id is case insensitive ,i will mark this answer as accepted.Thanks for your answer

Comment: @DhanrajTijare This is the doc what you are looking for:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#general

Comment: Thankyou so much ..got it

Comment: Can't we say it an issue of azure?they should fix it

Comment: @DhanrajTijare You could post an issue in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues).

Answer (score 0):

is entrire id case insensitive ? If not this is bad bad design. if i want to co-relate info from two different api's and use this id for merging data, then its acceptable to say that entire id is case in-sensitive and i can lowercase entor id for indexing . but if just one small section of it is case insensitive, then you expect all developers using api to just to do regex match to change case and index .
Seriously what an excellant design ! If azure want to treat it as case insensitive field why not accept upper case in resource group but consistently return id in lower case on all api's .